# Why this simple Query doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql

i can't make it work this simple query,it gives me my "die" error

```
mysql_select_db("minigest_dev" , $con);
$query = "  SELECT * "
    . "FROM anag_c_indirizzi"
    . "WHERE id_cliente = '1';";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or
    die("query non valida: ". mysql_error());
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: Print out the generated statement and you'll see for yourself.

Comment: You need a space before your WHERE clause.

Comment: Did you actually *read* the error the die statement was outputting?

Comment: @ciaoben Next time, please print out the error details you are receiving as well. It greatly helps us to determine how we'll be able to help you more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your query is concatenated, it becomes `SELECT * FROM anag_c_indirizziWHERE id_cliente = '1'`. You need to add a space so that it becomes `[...] anag_c_indirizzi WHERE [...]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you append you need to take care of string. Just give one space `WHERE` clause starts.

```
mysql_select_db("minigest_dev" , $con);
$query = " SELECT * "
       . " FROM anag_c_indirizzi "
       . " WHERE id_cliente = 1;";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or
         die("query non valida: ". mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Your mistake that you are show error in or condition.

Note :    $query = "   SELECT * "
           . "FROM anag_c_indirizzi"
           . "WHERE id_cliente = '1';";

multiple semicolon not allow in sql plz remove one semicolon(;)

mysql_select_db("minigest_dev" , $con);

```
   $query = "   SELECT * 
           FROM anag_c_indirizzi
           WHERE id_cliente = '1'";

   $result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die('query non valida:' . mysql_error());
}
```